# Error using command 'make'： process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL

Tags: java, android, android-ndk

Error using `make` command！I don't know how to solve it。There are only two files(`makefile` and `test.c`)：

```
NDK_DIR := F:\NDK\android-ndk-r12b
NDK_TOOLCHAINS := $(NDK_DIR)\toolchains
NDK_BUILT := $(NDK_TOOLCHAINS)\x86-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin
NDK_GCC := $(NDK_BUILT)\i686-linux-android-gcc.exe
NKD_PLATFORMS := $(NDK_DIR)\platforms\android-15
NDK_INCLUDE := $(NKD_PLATFORMS)\arch-x86\usr\include
NDK_LIBRARY := $(NKD_PLATFORMS)\arch-x86\usr\lib

NDK_BUILD_FLAGS := -I $(NDK_INCLUDE)  -c  
NDK_LINK_FLAGS  := -Bdynamic -nostdlib  -L $(NDK_LIBRARY) -lc 

NDK_MODULE := test

$(NDK_MODULE) : $(NDK_MODULE).o
    $(NDK_GCC) $(NDK_LINK_FLAGS) -o $(NDK_MODULE) $(NDK_MODULE).o 

$(NDK_MODULE).o : $(NDK_MODULE).c
    $(NDK_GCC) $(NDK_BUILD_FLAGS) -o $(NDK_MODULE).o  $(NDK_MODULE).c 

install:
    adb push $(NDK_MODULE) /data/local/tmp 
    adb shell chmod 777 /data/local/tmp/$(NDK_MODULE) 
    adb shell /data/local/tmp/$(NDK_MODULE) 
clean:
    del *.o
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc ,char *argv[])
{
    printf("hello world!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

NDK The version used is: `F:\NDK\android-ndk-r12b`

Cause of error

I don't know why the picture can't be displayed：

```
F:\NDK\android-ndk-r12b\toolchains\x86-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\i686-linu
x-android-gcc.exe -I F:\NDK\android-ndk-r12b\platforms\android-15\arch-x86\usr\i
nclude  -c   -o test.o  test.c
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, F:\NDK\android-ndk-r12b\toolchains\x86-4.9\pr
ebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\i686-linux-android-gcc.exe -I F:\NDK\android-ndk-r12b\
platforms\android-15\arch-x86\usr\include -c -o test.o test.c, ...) failed.
make (e=2):
make: *** [test.o] Error 2
```

Comment: Does the command that `CreateProcess` is trying to run work if you run it yourself? And is there any particular reason why you're not using `ndk-build`?

Comment: Also, why the ancient NDK? The current release is R21 and can still build for android-15.